# More efficient estimator in this situation?

Tags: estimation, sampling, estimators

I am thinking about the following situation (it is an example):
There are N families in a city and we have a simple random sample of size n. In that sample we know that there are $x_{0}$ families with 0 children, $x_{1}$ families with 1 child, $x_{2}$ families with 2 children...and $x_{5}$ families with 5 children. 
Apart from that information, we know that M families **in the city** have **no** children. In order to estimate the total number of children in the city, can anybody help me find a more efficient estimator than N times the mean of the sample?
I don´t know how to use in that case the ratio estimator or the regression estimator (I think I should use something related to ratio estimator but I don´t know how). Do I have to work with proportions? Any idea??

Comment: Are those numbers supposed to be subscripts, e.g., $x_0, x_1, x_2\dots$, or coefficients?   I suspect the former, in which case it would be helpful if you would use mathjax to 'typeset" your math.

Comment: Just edited! Any idea??